# Заменить текст в переменной

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Вот, к примеру, есть переменная с текстом «Привет %s. Добро пожаловать на %s. И %s тебе.»
Как заменить %s на нужные мне слова. 
Есть список слов «юзер», «сайт», «хорошего дня».
И после замены ы переменной должен быть уже такой текст:
«Привет юзер. Добро пожаловать на сайт. И хорошего дня тебе.»

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет. Можно примерно так:

```
$str = 'Привет %s. Добро пожаловать на %s. И %s тебе.';
$name = 'Вася';
$site = 'www.xxx.com';
$hi = 'доброго дня';
$str = sprintf($str, $name, $site, $hi);
// Выведем строку для просмотра результата
echo $str;
```

Это просто пример, а дальше можешь реализовать как тебе будет угодно.

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

**Можно так:**

```
$arr1 = array("Привет %s", "Добро пожаловать на %s", "И %s тебе");
$arr2 = array("юзер", "сайт", "хорошего дня");

for($i = 0;$i<=count($arr1)-1;$i++)
$text[$i] = str_replace("%s",$arr2[$i], $arr1[$i]);

echo($text[0])."<br>";
echo($text[1])."<br>";
echo($text[2]);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можно только так или же есть специальная функция в PHP?